# How did Windows Memory Diagnostic cause an SSD to suddenly become detected by both the BIOS and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, sata, hardware-detection

I have just bought a SATA Samsung EVO 870. After installation it was not visible to BIOS or Disk Management/Device Manager.
I tried using the cables directly removed from a working drive, new cables - data and power, hot boots, cold boots, leaving the mains unplugged for 10 minutes, different SATA ports, updating the BIOS and fiddling with the hot-plug/various disk controller options in the BIOS with no success.

At this point I suspected a DOA drive, but before RMAing it I decided to try a suggestion I saw on YouTube that running Windows Memory Diagnostics would cause the drive to become visible. I ran it, it found no errors, and the drive was immediately visible in both BIOS and Disk Management and has continued to be seen by both reliably on hot or cold boots.

The machine had been hot and cold booted with no further changes before trying the memory diagnostic, so it was not a coincidence with another change having been made.

My question is...how did this possibly work?

Comment: Similar thing happened to me. Bought a 6TB Toshiba, visible only in Bios and  Windows 10 Device manager with "Show hidden devices" ticked, but not in Disk Management. Running memory diagnostic fixed the problem, go figure...